# How to remove elements from multiple sublists according to another sublist in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `J` and removing elements from `J` according to `index`. I am trying to remove elements of `J[0]=[2, 6, 9, 10]` according to `index[0]=[0,3]`. Now after removing, I have `J=[6,9]` which should append to create `[[2, 6, 9, 10], [6, 9]]`. Now it should take `[6,9]` and remove element according to `index[1]=[1]`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
J=[[2, 6, 9, 10]]

index=[[0,3],[1]]

u=0

for v in range(0,len(index)): 
    new_J = [j for i, j in enumerate(J[u]) if i not in index[v]]
    J.append(new_J)

print(J)
```

The current output is

```
[[2, 6, 9, 10], [6, 9], [2, 9, 10]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[2, 6, 9, 10], [6, 9], [6]]
```

Comment: delete `u=0` and use `v` instead of `u`.

Comment: why `[0,3]` should result to `[6, 9]` (exclusive) and `[1]` to `[6]`(inclusive) ?

Comment: You forgot to add `u += 1` at the end of for loop

Comment: The expected output doesn't match the description. Your current output matches the description

Comment: I have provided more explanation on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate

J = [[2, 6, 9, 10]]
idx = [[0,3], [1]]
J = list(accumulate(idx, lambda lst, idx: [v for i, v in enumerate(lst) if i not in idx],
                    initial=J[-1]))
```

---

```
[[2, 6, 9, 10], [6, 9], [6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take your example, try this:

```py
J=[[2, 6, 9, 10]]

index=[[0,3],[1]]

u=0

for v in range(0,len(index)): 
    new_J = [j for i, j in enumerate(J[-1]) if i not in index[v]]
    J.append(new_J)

print(J)
```

Comment: The answers of replacing u with v from @Julien  and `u=u+1` of  @Ersel Er were both right.